# How do Music.app and ID3 differ regarding copyright notice?

Tags: music, id3-tag, copyright

How does Music.app find and display a copyright notice in the File tab of songs?

If I open a purchased track and an edited MP3 in [Amadeus Pro](https://hairersoft.com/pro.html), it shows the copyright notice for both as "Copyright Notice" in its "Additional" tab.

But in Music’s Info pane, it only appears for the Purchased file.

[eyeD3](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does not show it for either song file.

exiftool shows it for both with a tag name of "Copyright"

I have more than half of an audio editing task automated, and I'd like to script adding the copyright notice, instead of pasting it in manually.  exiftool can’t write to MP3 files, and eyeD3 doesn't have copyright in its options.  I’d also like to have Music.app display the notice for all files.

Comment: Copyright is just a standard ID3 tag.  The Music App is not a tag editor and has it’s own way of handling things.  What exactly do you want to do with these tags - the title and question don’t exactly mesh

Comment: I want to make it easier to put the tag in, and get Music to display it.  Which requires knowing how it is handled in ID3 and Music.

Comment: Upvoted this interesting question!

Answer (score 1):

Further investigation reveals:

A purchased AAC file has a copyright notice and a purchase date embedded in the file, and exiftool can read that.  Music (Get Info) displays both.

When Music creates an MP3 version, it removes the purchase date but not the copyright notice, but it still displays both.  It also adds a "Copyright Flag: False" but that does not stop it from displaying the notice and the date.

If Amadeus saves the file as MP3, it also removes the purchase date and not the copyright notice, but if imported into Music, the flag is still there and Music does NOT display the notice or the date.